# unable to install micro-ros-agent on raspberrypi

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

error: snap "micro-ros-agent" is not available on stable for this architecture (arm64) but exists
on other architectures (amd64).

is there any walk around on this as i ll need the raspberrypi 4 to work with my pico using ros2-foxy and micro-ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392946/unable-to-install-micro-ros-agent-on-raspberrypi./) by [aniketwagh](https://answers.ros.org/users/90068/aniketwagh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you can build the micro-ROS agent in a Raspberry Pi using the micro_ros_setup package. You can find more information here: https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_setup#building-micro-ros-agent

If you have further problems please open an issue in our Github repos to allow us to track and solve the problems.

Thanks a lot for using micro-ROS!

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aniketwagh](https://answers.ros.org/users/90068/aniketwagh/) on 2021-12-17**:
https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_setup/issues/438#issue-1083370759
@pablogs here i have created the issue please check